# How to fix the php memory issue on a loop

Tags: php

I have a loop that generates all the possible combinations of bits by giving the number of bits desired, bu the issue is that I got out of memory when number of bits goes beyond 20, is there any optimizations that I can do, to solve this issue.

here my code :

```
function bitsGenerator($N)
{
    $listN = $N;
    $bits = ['0', '1'];

    //check if input is valid or not
    if (!is_int($listN)) {
        echo 'Input must be numeric!';
    }

    if ($listN >= 1 && $listN <= 65) {
        if ($listN == 1) {
            echo '1';
            exit;
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($listN - 1); $i++) {
            $reverseBits = array_reverse($bits);

            $prefixBit = preg_filter('/^/', '0', $bits);

            $prefixReverseBits = preg_filter('/^/', '1', $reverseBits);

            $bits = array_merge($prefixBit, $prefixReverseBits);

            unset($prefixBit, $prefixReverseBits, $reverseBits);
        }

        $finalBits = array_slice($bits, -$listN);

        foreach ($finalBits as $k => $v) {
            echo $v . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid input!';
    }
}
```

The purpose of this function is to get the last `$N` combinations and display them all other combinations are thrown away, I'm looking for some kind of optimization to my code so that the $bits array will not store more than **65** item because the maximum number to bits thus the maximum number of combination to display is 65.

Thanks to every one for helping me.

Comment: search `memory_limit` in you php.ini file and increase the value.

Comment: Add `ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");` in the first line of your page...

Comment: Best optimisation is not to build large arrays in memory; can't you just echo each result out as you build it rather than adding it to an array using array_merge()?

Comment: @MarkBaker I have to add them to an array in order to manipulate the results after it finishes

Comment: Not necessarily so.... what are you doing with them once it's finished? Can you use a Generator instead of an array? Building large arrays in memory is never a good idea

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you please show me how to achieve the echo turnaround?

Comment: Isn't there any solution for that?

Comment: @MarkBaker I've edited my question, pplease check the bottom part.

Comment: @RahmaniSaif There may be ways to make this more effective. Not sure if you can keep it in the limit though. What's your max memory?

Comment: @user2693053 256MB

Comment: At first I thought storing integers or actual binary values may help. Strings take 8 bits per character (if I'm not mistaken). However... you're trying to store all possible combinations with 65 bits. If my math is not wrong that's: `2^65 combinations * 65 bits per combination`, or 299 759.591 petabytes. Please tell me my math is off, otherwise this is going to impossible on a normal system/server.

Comment: yes sir that's the issue I run on, I'm looking for something to empty the array (or reset it) ona certaon threshold

Comment: In the end you'll need that amount of memory (i.e. RAM) somehow to store the final result. Even writing them to a file would require an insane amount of storage. What's the end result you're trying to achieve -- how does this fit into the bigger picture? Even for `$N = 30` you'd need about 9GBs of RAM.

Comment: I got some kind of solution in my mind but I can't find got to code it, my solution is that to empty the array whenever the array reaches 2k elements, I've tried to `unset` the array and then re-declare it as an empty array inside the loop but it does not work

Comment: Can you tell us how you want to "manipulate the results after it finishes"? Maybe there's a solution there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the size of the `$bits` array holding all your results. The array will contain 2^$N elements, each of $N length times 8 bits for each character (because you are using strings to have leading zeroes) so you'll end up with a memory consumption of approx (2^$N)*$N*8 which is 167772160 bytes. It won't get any smaller when using RAM.

Your working copies of `$bits`, `preg_filter` and `array_merge` will also consume a lot of RAM. Running your function with `$N = 20` consumes 180375552 (172MiB).

BTW: `unset`ing the variables will not reduce the consumed RAM because they would get overwritten in the next iteration anyway (or destroyed at the end of the function)

The following function was my first sketch based on your function and uses a bit less RAM: 171970560 bytes or 164MiB (vs 172MiB).

```
function myBitsGenerator($length)
{
    if (!is_int($length)) {
        die('Input must be numeric!');
    }

    if ($length < 1 || $length > 65) {
        die('Input must be between 1 and 65');
    }

    $bitsArray = ['0', '1'];
    $count = 2;

    if ($length > 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
                $bitsArray[] = $bitsArray[$j] . '1';
                $bitsArray[$j] = $bitsArray[$j] . '0';
            }
            $count += $j;
        }
    }

    $printArray = array_slice($bitsArray, $count - $length);

    array_walk(
        $printArray,
        function ($value) {
            echo $value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    );
}
```

However, the generation of those numbers is too complicated and should be simplified:

**Theoretical**: A binary number can be written in decimal and vice versa. The number of possible combinations of binary numbers with the fixed length of $N are `x = 2 ^ $N`. Each decimal number from 0 to x represents a binary number in the results.

**Practical example**: (binary) (0b101 === 5) (int)

**All you have to do** is to pad the calculated binary number with zeroes.

The simplified generator looks like:

```
    $n = pow(2, $length);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        $binary = str_pad(decbin($i), $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

You can use this generator to generate

If you really need to use even less RAM you should think about storing it in a file, which makes the whole think slower but it will use way less RAM.

```
function fileBitsGenerator($length)
{
    $handle = fopen('bits.txt', 'w+');

    $iterations = pow(2, $length);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        fwrite($handle, str_pad(decbin($i), $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

This consumes just 2097152 bytes and scales!
But be aware that the performance will depend on your HDD/SSD speed and it executes a lot of write operations (which might shorten your SSD life span). For example: the resulting file bits.txt is 92MB big if `length = 22`

Comment: BTW you can control offset and limit by manipulating `$i` (e.g. initialize it with `$i = $iterations - $length` to generate only the last `$length` entries